# Complicated INNER JOIN that connect a table to itself

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I'm a beginner in using SQL queries, and want to make an inner `JOIN` statement that joins on the same table, and the other one at last.

This is my `JOIN` statement:

```sql
INNER JOIN (JOIN Categories ON Categories.PID=Categories.ID) 
ON categories.ID = categories_links.CID
```

Comment: Can you share you whole query, and explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: sorry.code is:  inner  JOIN (JOIN Categories  ON       Categories.PID=Categories.ID) ON categories.ID = categories_links.CID

Comment: Could you show us your table structure and what you're actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Categories a
JOIN Categories b
  ON a.PID=b.ID
JOIN categories_links c  
  ON a.ID = c.CID
```

Answer (score 1):

It's no more complicated than joining different tables.

```
SELECT ...
FROM Categories AS c1
INNER JOIN Categories AS c2 ON c1.PID = c2.ID
INNER JOIN Categories_links AS cl ON cl.CID = c1.ID
```

I'm not really sure whether the last join should use `c1` or `c2`, since your question isn't very clear. If you post some sample data and the desired results, I can fix it if necessary.